# Save images with CURL, sometimes it saves blank images

Tags: php, image, curl, save-image

I have this script where I fetch image links from specific websites, therefore I created a function where I pass the image link and source name of the website which will be used for placing the images on their corresponding directories.

However sometimes this function wouldn't work properly, randomly it would save the image however the image is basically empty, thus it would just save an empty file with the original filename from the $img_link, but fails to show the actual image.

In that case if that happens I tried to return me a default image path. But it fails to do so and returns an empty image as explained above.

```
function saveIMG($img_link, $source){

$name = basename($img_link); // gets basename of the file image.jpg
$name = date("Y-m-d_H_i_s_") . mt_rand(1,999) . "_" .$name;
if (!empty($img_link)){
    $ch = curl_init($img_link);
    $fp = fopen("images/$source/$name", 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);

    $name ="images/$source/$name";
    return $name;
}
else {
    $name = "images/news_default.jpg";
    return $name;
   }
}
```

Do you have any better idea, how to make a case when it fails to get retrieve an image?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`file_get_content`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is always a good alternative to cURL.

But, if you want/have to use cURL:

```
$ch = curl_init("www.path.com/to/image.jpg");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); //Return the transfer so it can be saved to a variable
$result = curl_exec($ch);  //Save the transfer to a variable
if($result === FALSE){//curl_exec will return false on failure even with returntransfer on
    //return? die? redirect? your choice.
}
$fp = fopen("name.jpg", 'w'); //Create the empty image. Extension does matter.
fwrite($fp, $result); //Write said contents to the above created file
fclose($fp);  //Properly close the file
```

And that's it. Tested it and it works.

Comment: This is nice, but I'd put the `fopen()` *after* the `$result` is collected, so that you can test the result and see if it's valid even before you bother opening the file to write.

Comment: @Andrew , I previously used file_get_content , but I think using cURL it showed better results.

Anyway I modified my function using your advice and so far it is working great. 

Thanks man :)

Answer (score 1):

use file get contents

```
$data = file_get_contents($img_link);
//check  it return data or not
if ( $data === false )
{
   echo "failed";
}
```